# Android Camera Video Recording issue

Tags: android, camera, android-camera2, recording, video-recording

I have created a project in which I am recording a video.When i am running the project in `Android 8.1.0` then getting below error.
 `android "mediarecorder: start failed: -19"` on `recorder.start()`.

I am using code

```
private void startRecording() {

    try {

        if (checkAvailabity()) {
            flashOn();
            findViewById(R.id.btn_fail).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            prepareRecorder();
            isRecordVideoClicked = true;
            isPriviewVideoClicked = false;
            enablePassButton();
            mThumbnail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            timerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
            filePathLabel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            filePathValue.setText("");

            recordingIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            startTime = 0L;

            timeInMilliseconds = 0L;

            timeSwapBuff = 0L;

            updatedTime = 0L;
            startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
            recording = true;

            recorder.start();
            start.setEnabled(false);
            start.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_disabled);

            AppLogger.v(this, TAG, "Recording Started");
        } else {
            findViewById(R.id.btn_pass).setEnabled(false);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        mThumbnail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        timerValue.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        filePathLabel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        recordingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Toast.makeText(CameraVideoTestActivity.this, R.string.error_on_video_recording, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
}

private void prepareRecorder() {
    try {
        int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        //recorder.setVideoSize(320, 240);
        recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
        if (cameraFront) {
            CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
            rotation = (info.orientation - 90 + 360) % 360;
            recorder.setOrientationHint(rotation);
        } else {
            recorder.setOrientationHint(ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
        }

        if (usecamera) {
            camera.lock();
            camera.unlock();
            recorder.setCamera(camera);

        }
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

        recorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile);

        if (camcorderProfile.fileFormat == MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP) {
            createthreeGppFile();
        } else {
            createOtherFormateVideo();
        }
        recorder.prepare();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        setTestPerformed(true);
        supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();

        AppLogger.exception(this, getClass().getSimpleName(), e);
    }
}
```

And i am using below code to prepare the Camera

```
 private void prepareCamera() throws Exception {
    parameters = camera.getParameters();

    List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    Camera.Size previewSize = previewSizes.get(0);
    parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
    parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(camcorderProfile.videoFrameRate);

    camera.setParameters(parameters);

    camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    camera.startPreview();
    previewRunning = true;

}
```

And in onSurface created using below code

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        AppLogger.v(this, TAG, "surfaceCreated");

        if (usecamera) {
            releaseCameraAndPreview();
            if (cameraFront) {
                if (camcorderProfile.fileFormat == MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP) {
                    camcorderProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW);
                } else {
                    camcorderProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(findFrontFacingCamera(), CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW);
                }
                camera = Camera.open(findFrontFacingCamera());

            } else {
                camcorderProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(findBackFacingCamera(), CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
                camera = Camera.open(findBackFacingCamera());
            }
            if (camera == null) {
                start.setEnabled(false);
                start.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_disabled);
                setTestPerformed(true);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            } else {
                start.setEnabled(true);
                start.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shadow);
                start.setPadding(20, 0, 20, 0);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        AppLogger.exception(this, getClass().getSimpleName(), e);
    }

}
```

Please provide some solution.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After spending 1 day I got the solution, just change the below code and now everything is working properly.

```
 recorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_720P));
```

Comment: This will not work on all devices, you have to check if the profile is available before setting it. You can check the available sizes and set the profile to the highest according to the size.